# Use a 'foreach' loop for drawing a staircase in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I’m trying to draw a staircase where I can set the number of stairs, i.e., `\renewcommand{/stairs}{5}` and it will create the stairs. I believe a *for* each loop can accomplish this. How can I simplify my code?

Ideally I would like to set the number of stairs, set the riser and tread lengths where they will display as well. For example, could I make the stair number 7 and it will automatically create the 7 steps for me?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc,matrix,tikzmark,positioning,patterns,decorations.markings,trees,angles,quotes,fit,math}
\printanswers
% \usepackage{showframe}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{dir1/stairs.png}
\newcommand{\stepstemporary}{4*\tread}
\newcommand{\Width}{3.4}
\newcommand{\riserheight}{0.6}
\newcommand{\tread}{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{outline}=[thick]
% \node(P) at (1.5,2.25) {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{dir1/stairs.png}};
\coordinate(A) at (0,0);
\coordinate(B) at ($(A)+(20:\Width)$);
\coordinate(C) at ($(A)+(90:\riserheight)+(155:\tread)$);
\coordinate(D) at ($(A)+(90:2*\riserheight)+(155:2*\tread)$);
\coordinate(E) at ($(A)+(90:3*\riserheight)+(155:3*\tread)$);
\coordinate(F) at ($(A)+(90:4*\riserheight)+(155:4*\tread)$);

%front side stringer
\draw[outline,fill=gray!50](A)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(0,-4*\riserheight)--cycle;
%back side stringer
\draw[outline,fill=gray!50]($(A)+(20:\Width)$)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(0,-4*\riserheight)--cycle;
%front riser
\draw[fill=gray!40](A)--++(20:\Width)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(200:\Width);
\draw[fill=gray!40](C)--++(20:\Width)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(200:\Width);
\draw[fill=gray!40](D)--++(20:\Width)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(200:\Width);
\draw[fill=gray!40](E)--++(20:\Width)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(200:\Width);
%%treads lighter colour
\draw[fill=gray!10](C)--++(20:\Width)--++(-25:\tread)--++(200:\Width)--cycle;

\draw[fill=gray!10](D)--++(20:\Width)--++(-25:\tread)--++(200:\Width)--cycle;

\draw[fill=gray!10](E)--++(20:\Width)--++(-25:\tread)--++(200:\Width)--cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!10](F)--++(20:\Width)--++(-25:\tread)--++(200:\Width)--cycle;

\draw[|-|]([shift=(300:5mm)]A)--node[sloped,fill=white]{120 cm}([shift=(300:5mm)]B);

\draw[|-|]([shift=(20:5mm)]$(C)+(20:\Width)$)--node[,xshift=1cm,fill=white]{20 cm}([shift=(20:5mm)]$(20:\Width)+(0,\riserheight)$);

\draw[|-|]([shift=(20:0mm)]$(A)+(20:\Width)+(0,3*\riserheight)$)--node[,xshift=1cm,fill=white]{18 cm}([shift=(20:0mm)]$(A)+(20:\Width)+(0,2*\riserheight)$);
% \foreach \i in {1,...\steps}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to somewhat accomplish this picture:  [image: staircase]

Comment: Alternatively (in sufficiently complex cases) write Lua/Python code to generate TeX code instead. (with LuaTeX/PythonTeX respectively) Complex TeX code isn't exactly easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

[image]

If you reformat your *front side stringer* code as

```
\draw[outline,fill=red!50](A)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(0,-4*\riserheight)
    --cycle;
```

then it is easy to see that this can be converted to a `foreach` loop as:

```
\draw[outline,fill=red!50](A)--++(90:\riserheight)
\foreach \StairNum in {2,...,\steps} {
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
} 
--++(155:\tread)--++(0,-\steps*\riserheight)
-- cycle;
```

Similarily for the steps you just need to compute the new coordinates for the endpoints:

```
\foreach \StairNum in {1,...,\steps} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\StairNumMinusOne}{\StairNum-1}%
    \coordinate (X) at ($(90:(\StairNumMinusOne*\riserheight)+(155:\StairNumMinusOne*\tread)$);
    \coordinate (Y) at ($(90:\StairNum*\riserheight)+(155:\StairNum*\tread)$);
    %front riser
    \draw[fill=blue!40](X)--++(20:\Width)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(200:\Width);
    %%treads lighter colour
    \draw[fill=blue!10](Y)--++(20:\Width)--++(-25:\tread)--++(200:\Width)--cycle;
}
```

#### Notes:

- I did not include the *back side stringer* as that seems to not be visible anyway.
- The dimensioning also needs work.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc,matrix,tikzmark,positioning,patterns,decorations.markings,trees,angles,quotes,fit,math}
\printanswers

\pagecolor{white}
% \usepackage{showframe}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%\includegraphics[width=8cm]{dir1/stairs.png}
\newcommand{\steps}{7}
\newcommand{\stepstemporary}{\steps*\tread}
\newcommand{\Width}{3.4}
\newcommand{\riserheight}{0.6}
\newcommand{\tread}{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{outline}=[thick]
% \node(P) at (1.5,2.25) {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{dir1/stairs.png}};
\coordinate(A) at (0,0);
\coordinate(B) at ($(A)+(20:\Width)$);
\coordinate(C) at ($(A)+(90:\riserheight)+(155:\tread)$);
\coordinate(D) at ($(A)+(90:2*\riserheight)+(155:2*\tread)$);
\coordinate(E) at ($(A)+(90:3*\riserheight)+(155:3*\tread)$);
\coordinate(F) at ($(A)+(90:4*\riserheight)+(155:4*\tread)$);

front side stringer
\draw[outline,fill=red!50](A)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
    --++(155:\tread)--++(0,-4*\riserheight)
    --cycle;
%%back side stringer
%\draw[outline,fill=red!50]($(A)+(20:\Width)$)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(155:\tread)--++(0,-4*\riserheight)--cycle;

\draw[outline,fill=black!50](A)--++(90:\riserheight)
\foreach \StairNum in {2,...,\steps} {
    --++(155:\tread)--++(90:\riserheight)
} 
--++(155:\tread)--++(0,-\steps*\riserheight)
-- cycle;

\foreach \StairNum in {1,...,\steps} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\StairNumMinusOne}{\StairNum-1}%
    \coordinate (X) at ($(90:(\StairNumMinusOne*\riserheight)+(155:\StairNumMinusOne*\tread)$);
    \coordinate (Y) at ($(90:\StairNum*\riserheight)+(155:\StairNum*\tread)$);
    %front riser
    \draw[fill=blue!40](X)--++(20:\Width)--++(90:\riserheight)--++(200:\Width);
    %%treads lighter colour
    \draw[fill=blue!10](Y)--++(20:\Width)--++(-25:\tread)--++(200:\Width)--cycle;
}

\draw[|-|]([shift=(300:5mm)]A)--node[sloped,fill=white]{120 cm}([shift=(300:5mm)]B);

\draw[|-|]([shift=(20:5mm)]$(C)+(20:\Width)$)--node[,xshift=1cm,fill=white]{20 cm}([shift=(20:5mm)]$(20:\Width)+(0,\riserheight)$);

\draw[|-|]([shift=(20:0mm)]$(A)+(20:\Width)+(0,3*\riserheight)$)--node[,xshift=1cm,fill=white]{18 cm}([shift=(20:0mm)]$(A)+(20:\Width)+(0,2*\riserheight)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a unit-staircase with `\stairs` number of steps. It is stretched dependent on view angle, `\width`, `\riserheight` and `\tread`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\stairs}{5}
\newcommand{\width}{3.4}
\newcommand{\riserheight}{0.6}
\newcommand{\tread}{0.5}
\begin{scope}[x={(1.2*\tread cm,-0.8*\tread cm)}, y={(1*\width cm,0.8*\width cm)}, z={(0 cm,\riserheight cm)}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,\stairs} {
  \fill[gray!10] (\i-1,0,{\stairs-\i+1}) -- (\i-1,1,{\stairs-\i+1}) -- (\i,1,{\stairs-\i+1}) -- (\i,0,{\stairs-\i+1}) -- cycle;
  \fill[gray!40] (\i,0,{\stairs-\i}) -- (\i,1,{\stairs-\i}) -- (\i,1,{\stairs+1-\i}) -- (\i,0,{\stairs+1-\i}) -- cycle;
}
\draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\stairs) \foreach \i in {1,...,\stairs} {-- (\i,0,{\stairs+1-\i}) -- (\i,0,{\stairs+1-\i-1})} -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,\stairs) -- (0,1,\stairs)  \foreach \i in {1,...,\stairs} {-- (\i,1,{\stairs+1-\i}) -- (\i,1,{\stairs+1-\i-1})} -- (\stairs,0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Stairs]